# lombok - cannot find symbol getId()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

Hi I am doing simple application on Spring boot MongoDB example.

I am getting this error while I run my sprint boot main class:

```
BookController.java
Error:(26, 54) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable book of type com.javatechie.spring.mongo.api.model.Book
```

I found some solution on stack overflow, I changed

1. Installed Lomboc plugin.
2. Enabled Settings -> ... Compiler -> Annotation Processors
3. Enabled Other Settings -> ... Compiler -> Annotation Processors

   Still I am facing same issue.
   I am using IDEA 2019.3.4 Community Version in Windows 10.

Comment: Did you restart your IDE?

Comment: do you mean Lombok? if so have you annotated your class with @Data.

Comment: Yes, I restarted after lombok is installed.

Comment: Please show us the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. But the exact reason I don't know. I changed to Spring boot 2.2.0 to 2.2.6. And deleted the target folder and did maven clean compile. And started the application as usual. Now it working fine.